# Selecting columns from eager-loaded laravel models

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I'm trying to select columns from related models, but I'm not quite sure how to do it using Eloquent (I want to avoid the DB namespace).

This is what I have so far...

```
$users = User::with("role", "country") -> select(["first_name", "last_name", "email_address"]);
```

How would I go about modifying the select list so that it also includes `role.title` and `country.name`?

So essentially, my select list would look something like this:

```
-> select(["first_name", "last_name", "email_address", "role.title", "country.name"]);
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
User::with(['role' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('title');
}])->with(['country' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('name');
}])->get();
```

or

```
User::with([
    'role' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('title');
    },
    'country' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('name');
    }
])->get();
```